# How to parse and validate Cloud Task token in Firebase HTTP function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security, google-cloud-tasks

I have a node.js application that creates [Cloud HTTP tasks with authentication](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-create-http-task-with-token). I'd like to handle these tasks viaFirebase HTTP function (also in JS). I understand that I need to use `oidcToken` when creating a task, but I don't understand how to validate such a token on the Firebase HTTP function end. Docs are not very helpful. I was expecting to find some utility in `@google-cloud/tasks` or in `googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs`, but nothing jump out at me.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is assosiacte your Cloud Function with a service account. This is called [Function Identity](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity#individual). Please note that whenever you deploy a Cloud Function either in GCP or Firebase, the same function appears in both platforms.

You can create a new service account for this purpose with:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts create [YOUR_NEW_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME] \
  --display-name "Service Account Test"
```

And assign the required IAM role with:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} \
  --member serviceAccount:[YOUR_NEW_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --role roles/cloudfunctions.invoker
```

Your function deployment should look like something like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy hello_world \
  --trigger-http \
  --region us-central1 \
  --runtime nodejs14 \
  --service-account [YOUR_NEW_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
  --no-allow-unauthenticated
```

Once you have all that, your Cloud HTTP task should use this service account as the OICD token, but I believe you already know how to do so.

You can find more information in this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/using-scheduler-invoke-private-functions-oidc) (although it uses the Cloud Scheduler instead of Cloud Tasks, the idea is pretty much the same).

Comment: I should have been more specific. There are 2 applications: one is a node app that creates Cloud Tasks, another app is a Firebase application where Cloud Tasks are received by an HTTP function. So the question is how to perform token validation in that HTTPS Cloud Function handler in the Firebase environment.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to validate the token in the function, when you create the function so only authenticated users can call it this verification will automatically be done on Google's side.

So, to make what you want you need to:

### 1. Create the Task Queue

Detailed steps in this [how-to](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues).

### 2. Create the service account

You will need to create a SA with these IAM permissions:

- Cloud Functions Invoker
- Cloud Tasks Enqueuer
- Service Account User

"Cloud Functions Invoker" is necessary to be able to call the function and  "Cloud Tasks Enqueuer" to add tasks to the queue. If you want to use a different SA for each of those steps you can separate these permissions.

### 3. Create the Firebase Functions function

When creating the function, make sure that it required authentication.

### 4. Create the task using the SA

There's a section for this in the documentation, which you can find [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#token). The code below is copied below:

```js
// Imports the Google Cloud Tasks library.
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');

// Instantiates a client.
const client = new CloudTasksClient();

async function createHttpTaskWithToken() {
    const project = '[PROJECT_NAME]';
    const queue = '[QUEUE_NAME]';
    const location = '[LOCATION]';
    const url = '[FUNCTION_TREIGGER_URL]';
    const serviceAccountEmail = '[SA]';
    const payload = 'Hello, World!';

  // Construct the fully qualified queue name.
  const parent = client.queuePath(project, location, queue);

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url,
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail,
      },
    },
  };

  if (payload) {
    task.httpRequest.body = Buffer.from(payload).toString('base64');
  }

  console.log('Sending task:');
  console.log(task);
  // Send create task request.
  const request = {parent: parent, task: task};
  const [response] = await client.createTask(request);
  const name = response.name;
  console.log(`Created task ${name}`);
}
createHttpTaskWithToken();
```

Comment: `make sure that it required authentication` can you expand more on this? This answer seems incomplete as we still do not know how to access and validate the passed SA token in a Firebase onRequest function.